# Cookie value in requests session question?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

i'm trying to understand the need/point of the "sessions" method a bit more. Below i'm running a couple of API requests and using the requests.session method for the first section and after the hash tag line i'm not using it and running just a normal GET request and printing out the cookies for each request.

The print statements on the first block of code above the hash tag return the same cookie value twice and underneath there are 2 separate cookie values but it still works. Is this simply because there are 2 different requests not connected to each-other? Therefore return 2 separate cookie values? I thought that it may have been the same initially as the first block because i'm logging in getting something back from the API, how is the GET request working after the hashtag line when it's not using the same cookie value.

Thanks for the help

```
import requests

payload = {"j_username": "devnetuser", "j_password": "Cisco123!"}
sess = requests.session()
c = sess.post('https://sandboxsdwan.cisco.com:8443/j_security_check', data=payload, verify=False)
controllers_url = "https://sandboxsdwan.cisco.com:8443/dataservice/system/device/controllers"
response_controllers = sess.get(controllers_url, verify=False)
devices = response_controllers.json()['data']

for device in devices:
    print(f"Device Controller ----> {device['deviceIP']}")

print(sess.cookies)
<RequestsCookieJar[<Cookie JSESSIONID=d1EgqCTWTi_Z0SaWDZ3u4P06aSNDYdt0MFahBnRA.4854266f-a8ad-4068-9651-d4e834384f51 for sandboxsdwan.cisco.com/>]>

print(c.cookies)
<RequestsCookieJar[<Cookie JSESSIONID=d1EgqCTWTi_Z0SaWDZ3u4P06aSNDYdt0MFahBnRA.4854266f-a8ad-4068-9651-d4e834384f51 for sandboxsdwan.cisco.com/>]>

####################################################################################

sess2 = requests.post('https://sandboxsdwan.cisco.com:8443/j_security_check', data=payload, verify=False)
response_controllers2 = requests.get(controllers_url, verify=False)
devices = response_controllers.json()['data']

for device in devices:
    print(f"Device Controller ----> {device['deviceIP']}")

print(sess2.cookies)
<RequestsCookieJar[<Cookie JSESSIONID=AfB_f5b-xqYtTOLvoL9OGGC4jbnEoL8Sy3ipn0wz.4854266f-a8ad-4068-9651-d4e834384f51 for sandboxsdwan.cisco.com/>]>

print(response_controllers2.cookies)
<RequestsCookieJar[<Cookie JSESSIONID=dkt1tYOC9y1tY5MLKG0iWHWJeXQGAp5q_vQRi0oT.4854266f-a8ad-4068-9651-d4e834384f51 for sandboxsdwan.cisco.com/>]>
```

Comment: The GET request may complete, but are you getting the result you'd expect if you were logged in? It may just start a new session altogether, or return a response that doesn't have the content you'd be getting when logged in.

Comment: Have you tried simply performing the GET without logging in at all? Does that get you the same result, or different?

Comment: I think i know what i've done wrong, under the hashtag line i've retrieved the .json() info from the GET request in the first block of code (above the hash tag line). 
This in a weird way has made me understand how requests.sessions work now, because when i change (under the hashtag line) to devices = response_controllers2.json()['data'].......It doesn't work. Which means that it does infact need the same session cookie in order to work.

Does that seem right?

Comment: Yeah, looks like just a typo in your example, I expect the results you get if you turn that line into `devices = response_controllers2.json()['data']` match your expectations, so really nothing to see here?

Comment: Yeah nothing else, all sorted